# How do I compare 3 arraylists and replace data in the 3rd arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist, sms

I have a unique SMS problem:

The end goal is to replace the phone numbers displaying in my list to contact names

*(These are all string arraylists)*

**ArrayList3** contains 6 elements that represents a selection of phone numbers.
**ArrayList2** contains 31 elements representing all available phone numbers.
**ArrayList1** contains 31 elements representing the names of all phone numbers in the same order respectively to **ArrayList2.**

How would I compare them all to this effect:

"If **Arraylist3's** element is equal to an element in **ArrayList2**, copy **ArrayList3** at the same position of **ArrayList2** and place it into **ArrayList3."**

Roughly, what Im trying to do is match the elements of **ArrayList3** with identical elements in **ArrayList2**. From there, use the position of **ArrayList2** to get the same position of **ArrayList1**, then copy the data at that position (**ArrayList1**) into **ArrayList3**.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: what it means "copy ArrayList3 at the same position of ArrayList2 and place it into ArrayList3."?

Comment: Are all the arraylists of the same type?

Comment: @JakeWilson801 They are all ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following and it works for me:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList1.add("Welcome");
    arrayList1.add("Home");

    arrayList2.add("1");
    arrayList2.add("2");

    arrayList3.add("2");



    for(int i=0; i< arrayList3.size(); i++){
        if(arrayList2.contains(arrayList3.get(i))){
            int index = arrayList2.indexOf(arrayList3.get(i));
            arrayList3.set(i, arrayList1.get(index));
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Found " + arrayList3.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you count the complexity of you decision - how many times you will scan arrayList2 for each element

Comment: I accept that the solution provided by @Squonk is the optimized one but if @ ChocoMan doesn't want to change his data structure and wants to use the existing structure, he may employ the solution I provided

Comment: Thats was exactly what I wanted will holding the same structure. This worked for 1 name though.

Comment: @ChocoMan I am not sure what you mean when you say that the code worked for 1 name because I was able to get the `arraylist3` with multiple names updated with values from `arrayList1`. I added just a single value in `arraylist3` for simplicity but the code does work for multiple values.

Comment: For some reason when I applied your code, only arrayList3.get(2) changed to a name. All the other elements stayed as phone numbers. I also checked it in logcat and it says the same thing.

Comment: I also made a console version of your code and that worked like it was suppose to, so something unknown is causing only one name to change.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ArrayList<String>` for ArrayList1 and ArrayList2. Combine the data as `Map<String,String>`.

A Map basically uses `<key, value>` structure so instead of having `ArrayList1` containing 'names' and `ArrayList2` containing 'numbers', just take a `Map<name,number>` approach then find the value (i.e., number) obtained from `ArrayList3` in the `Map`.

See [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: I dont understand how to implement this entirely. Ive converted ArrayList1 and 2 into Strings to use with Map<>, but Im clueless as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are just trying to convert number in to name in ArrayList3 (with updaed index) using ArrayList1 (have names) and ArrayList2 (have numbers) in same order...............

You should use one more array list as you reading and writing data in the same ArrayList3. so it is possible that any of the name may replace the any number at i+ index which is not process's yet........

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. What I'm trying to do is match the name at ArrayList3 with ArrayList2. Then use the position of ArrayList2 to go to ArrayList1. Then replace the phone number at ArrayList3 with with the contact name from the position at ArrayList1.

Comment: ArrayList2 is just the middleman to connect ArrayList1 and 3 together. The only data that will change is ArrayList3. 3 compares with 2, then 2 compares with 1, then 3 is replaced with 1 if that makes sense.